# Why my trash icon doesn't work in 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, trash

I click on the trash icon in the launcher, but nothing happens!

Comment: Does `~/.local/share/Trash` exist?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm can access the trash by the nautilus. Only the icon in the launcher doesn't work.

Comment: After the last kernel update, the trash icon it's worked!
How can I sign this question as solved?

Comment: Add it as an answer then accept that answer (the green check mark).  That will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last kernel update, the problem was **SOLVED!**